How do I get the debugger on vs code to debug my COBOL program
i am new to learning Cobol. Taking the course on the IBM website. Learning Cobol Enterprise. Ran through all the setup steps, when trying to debug the program i get two errors.

File associations have been defined for COBOL which override the values required by the Rocket COBOL extension

To enable building and the debugger, you will need to install Visual COBOL or Enterprise Developer.


I have installed all extensions required for this course and still not getting any satisfaction. Has anyone had this before, if so what would be my next steps.
All extensions have been installed and followed directions as reuqested.

That error is exactly from the Rocket COBOL extension - just disable it for the workspace that you use for working on the zOS training machine (actually I'd suggest to use a separate clean profile for full separation).
If you want to run and debug COBOL outside of the Mainframe environment your best pick is likely the superbol extension (if you need the GnuCOBOL binaries - they also provide an installer for them).
